# Expo shared cookies between AuthSession and fetch

Tags: react-native, cookies, expo

Our expo app is using [`AuthSession`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v25.0.0/sdk/auth-session.html#content) to authenticate against our site. It looks like the `sessionid` cookie is set on the web view that `AuthSession` shows, but when I go to `fetch` on the same origin as the login, there are no cookies present.

here's what my `fetch` looks like:

```
return fetch(`${baseApiUrl}/${url}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  mode: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Origin: baseApiUrl
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(body)
});
```

The project is open source as well:

https://github.com/rit-bikeshare/mobile-app/blob/gd-auth/src/js/api/request.js

Comment: I just looked at your project, and it appears you've gone with JWT instead of using cookies? I'm still trying to figure this problem out at the moment so any insights you've find out would be greatly appreciated.